# Translating CodeIgniter's form validation error messages

Tags: php, codeigniter, localization, internationalization, validation

Is there anyway to translate CodeIgniter's form validation error messages without touching to system files?

Comment: this is my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36331269/3143384. We need to change in validation lang file but this way you can set custom message to any field.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are talking about actually translating to another language, this can be done by setting the config value `$config['language']` to the language you want. If you don't want to change the actual config.php file you can do it through the use of the Config object's `set_item()` function like this:

```
$this->config->set_item('language', 'spanish');
```

See: [CodeIgniter Doc for the Config Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html)

This assumes that you have a spanish directory in your `language` directory with at least the `form_validation_lang.php` file.

However, if you are just wanting to create custom messages for the Form_validation object, you can copy the `form_validation_lang.php` file from the `system\language` directory and move it to the `application\language` directory. You can now edit the new language file to make it reflect any different messages you want. You can also revert back to the default messages easily by removing the file from the `application/language` directory.

Another way to do it, if you don't want to touch even the `language` files is to manually override the messages. You can do that through the `Form_validation` library object like so:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'This is a required item!');`
```

See: [CodeIgniter Doc for the Form Validation Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors)

Comment: Language packs: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Language-Translation - However a lot of those links are dead unfortunately :(

Comment: Apply the method which @wescrow has mentioned. and go for language pack. Here is an official working new link for CI 3.x languages https://github.com/bcit-ci/codeigniter3-translations

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set a custom error message for a particular field on some particular rule, use the set_rules() method:

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('field_name', 'Field Label', 'rule1|rule2|rule3',
        array('rule2' => 'Error Message on rule2 for this field_name')
);
```

This will solve your all fields problem independently. :)