# Codeigniter Dual language form_error message

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing dual language site in codeigniter (English and French)

**I want to show validating error in both language**

When there is error i got this

In english

**The Password field is required**

In french

**The Mot de passe field is required.**

But i want all Full message in french

Like

**Le champ Mot de passe est requis**

............

I already created the language folder for the french and english

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070227/translating-codeigniters-form-validation-error-messages

Comment: thanks for rely.
I already go through that link and other also on stackoverflow.
I am switching the language in config file by my helper.
Added new language folder french and form_validation_lang file
but its take the message from the english system folder

and give me same message